# How to formulate sql request for paths generaion?

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data

I have two tables.

Table_one

| id | name | parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | brand | 0 |
| 2 | audi | 1 |
| 3 | q5 | 2 |
| 4 | 2011 | 3 |

…

Table_two

| id | path |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |
| 4 |  |

How do I make a request so that the path to each value appears in the "path" column of the second table, taking into account all its parents via "/"?

If successful, the second table should look like this:

Table_two

| id | path |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | brand/ |
| 2 | brand/audi |
| 3 | brand/audi/q5 |
| 4 | brand/audi/Q5/2011 |

…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL 8.0 solves this with a [recursive common table expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive):

```
with recursive cte as (
 select id, name
 from table_one where parent = 0
 union all
 select table_one.id, concat_ws('/', cte.name, table_one.name)
 from table_one join cte on table_one.parent = cte.id
)
select * from cte;
```

If you use an older version of MySQL 5.x, then it's time to upgrade to MySQL 8.0.